# Validate JSON Implicit as List or Type

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to convert a json string to a model `Temperature`. I am using it as a POST request. If I run the below as is it will go the JsError route and complain about a validation error that it is expecting a `List`. If I change the validate argument to `List[Temperature]` instead of just `Temperature` then it complains that there's no implicit definitions for `List`.

The json string I am passing is: `{"typeOfTemperature":"F", "tempVal":90.00}`

saveTemperature method:

```scala
def saveTemperature = Action { request =>
    request.body.asJson match {
      case Some(json) =>
        json.validate[Temperature] match {
          case s: JsSuccess[Temperature] => {
            val temperature: Temperature = s.get
            println(temperature)
            convert.qTemperature.enqueue(temperature)
            Ok
          }
          case e: JsError => {
            //val err: JsError = e.get
            println(e)
            Ok
          }
          case _ => Ok
        }
      case _ => BadRequest
    }
  }
```

Reads/Writes implicits:

```
  implicit val temperatureWrites: Writes[Temperature] = (
    (JsPath \ "typeOfTemp").write[String] and
      (JsPath \ "tempVal").write[Double]
    )(unlift(Temperature.unapply))

  implicit val tempReads: Reads[Temperature] = (
    (JsPath \ "typeOfTemp").read[String](minLength[String](2)) and
      (JsPath \ "tempVal").read[Double](min(-1000.0) keepAnd max(1000.0))
    )(Temperature.apply _)
```

Comment: your JSON key name should match the one in your reads example :```{"typeOfTemp":"F", "tempVal":90.00}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON key names should match with the implicit read key names.
Example :

```
{"typeOfTemp":"F", "tempVal":90.00}
```

Also, play provides outbox of support to automatically parse the request body as JSON.

Example :

```
Action(parse.json) { request =>

    request.body.validate[Temperature]
      .fold(
        errors => {
          //log error
          BadRequest(Json.obj("error" -> "invalid request"))
        },
          temperature => {
            println(temperature)
            Ok(Json.toJson(temperature))
          }
      )
  }
```